# A different network interface becomes the default route if the active default goes down

Tags: linux-networking

I have two network interfaces eth0 and eth1 and I just wanna know how get the "eth1" as default route automatically if the "eth0" goes down?

Comment: Please define goes down.  Does eth0 lose link or is does something upstream break?  Are eth0, and eth1 connected to the same switch, or are they connected to different routers/networks.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called `interface bonding` - There are lots of howtos on setting this up, [this one is good for bare-bones "type this" information](http://osthings.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/setting-up-bonding-in-linux-for-nics-redundancy/), and [this one has a little more information](http://www.linux-corner.info/bonding.html).

The [ifcfg-bonding](http://manpages.unixforum.co.uk/man-pages/linux/suse-linux-10.1/5/ifcfg-bonding-man-page.html) manpage (& references) may also be of help, and is probably more up-to-date than any tutorials you'd find by googling..

Comment: I hadn't considered bonding as the answer here, maybe simply because of the phrasing of OPs question.  This may be the right answer but its hard to tell.

Comment: @dmourati same way I didn't think of it being two NICs on different networks -- it's a bit vague :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the metric argument to `route`.   Metrics are counted as additional hops to the destination network or host.

```
route add default gw eth1defaultroute metric 10 dev eth1
```

This is the "old school" way of doing things.

You may also be interested to learn about iproute2:

```
ip route add default via eth1defaultroute metric 10 dev eth1
```

For more details, see:

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html

http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html#ss9.5.1

Comment: ... If you're talking about two NICs on different subnets this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Yet a third option is using BGP.